# I have two lists, I want to know if a date in one list is between two dates in another. How should I do this?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a list A that looks like this:

```
[((5.8, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 5, 2, 8, 47))]
```

I have another list B that looks like this:

```
[((date1, datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 8, 1, 34)),
(date2, datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 2, 1, 42)),
(date3, datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 2, 11, 23))]
```

I want to know if the date in list A is between any consecutive dates in list B.  In other words the output using the lists here would be:

```
[(5.8, date2)]
```

This is because the date in list A is between the first and second dates of list B. So I output the important value from list A (5.8) and (date2).  I would not use date1 or date3 because I want to make sure that the date from list 1 is in between two of the dates, and I use the latter date of the two dates as an output.

Comment: have you tried to solve this? can you show us some code

Comment: only in my head...I truly haven't a clue.  I am going to look into what zips are in Moinuddin Quadri's answer!

Comment: You should have broken down the problem to simpler component parts before asking. Suppose, instead of dates, you were using integers; would the solution be clear then? It comes down to a question of whether you can compare these `datetime` objects the same way you can compare integers; in other words, are they members of a totally ordered set. This sort of problem analysis is an essential skill for any programmer.

Comment: Your A and B both have syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

For achieving this via Brute-Force, you may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
import datetime

list_a = [(5.8, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 5, 2, 8, 47))]
#        v^  typo in actual list format       
list_b =[('date1', datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 8, 1, 34)),
          ('date2', datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 2, 1, 42)),
          ('date3', datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 2, 11, 23))]

my_list = [(num_a, str_b2) for num_a, date_a in list_a \
              for (str_b1, date_b1), (str_b2, date_b2) in zip(list_b, list_b[1:]) \
                   if date_b1 < a2 < date_b2]
```

Final content hold by `my_list` will be:

```
[(5.8, 'date2')]
```

Comment: Pretty concise, but a little hard on the eyes. If you have the time, I'm sure OP and future readers would appreciate variable names and indentation =)

Comment: `zip` is used to iterate over list B pairwise so that each element in list A is compared with each pair of adjacent elements in list B.

Comment: Is it looks ok now? I am scratching my head for putting the names to variables *tough job* :/

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri It's probably hard to name the variables because OP's use case for this sort of thing is pretty hard to guess.